# How do we get the remainder in division arithmetic for computer architecture?

Tags: math, hardware

I am learning binary division following the step-by-step procedure.  I am stuck at Step One Repeat One in the remainder section.  To get the remainder, the formula is Remainder = Remainder - Divisor.

How do we get to remainder: 11100110?  I just don't understand how we have 1110 on the left half of the register.  Any guides or help would greatly be appreciated!
Thanks:

The example is 10/5 using an 8 bit ALU.

I have attached a picture of the example for reference

[image]

Comment: Yes, it looks wrong to me too. I think it should be `10111010`.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic.  It should probably be migrated to cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I tried posting to cs.stackexchange, but due to my low reputation, I cannot upload any images to get my point across.  Sorry, please don't close.

Comment: Sounds like you need a copy of [Stallings](http://williamstallings.com/ComputerOrganization/).

Comment: CS crowd is mainly expecting theoretical and research stuff anyhow, so would not sit well there either.